# sppsvc.exe issue on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, process, services, cpu-usage

I have a PC with the following specs (AMDfx8350 - 16 GB RAM). It's not a super machine but is enough for my favorite games, studies and job.

Recently I noticed in Task manager a process called Software Protection Platform service (sppsvc.exe) that is putting an average of 15% to 20% of load on my CPU every 40 seconds in a lapse of 15 seconds. (The CPU usage raises every 40 seconds)

I use Windows 10 and I am new with this OS (I am from Win 7) and I don't recall ever noticing this process before. I want to know if this process and its behaviour is normal? If so, should it be this constant? Or, should I scan my PC for viruses?

I've already scanned my PC with MWB and Windows Defender, with zero threat results. Is there a way to stop this process without damaging another thing and/or without violating any security?

Comment: open a cmd.exe as admin, run **wpr.exe -start cpu** wait until the cpu usage is gone, now run **wpr.exe -stop C:\highCPUusage.etl**. now zip the **C:\highCPUusage.etl** and share the zip (onedrive), so that I can analyze it

Comment: were you able to repro the usage and have you captured the trace?

Comment: Sorry for my late answer, here is my capture [HighCPUusage](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AphuhmHafaC4bc_GE4mSrF7blNU)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sppsvc.exe is responsible for activating Windows. for this file Microsoft doesn't seam to provide the required debug symbols. So I can't see what it does in detail, but I see you use a KMS crack (`C:\Windows\KMS-R@1n.exe`) to activate Windows 10 Pro. Next I see that you use the older November 2015 Version 1511 with an old patch level from February 2016 (`10586.162.amd64fre.th2_release_sec.160223-1728`).

To fix your issue, remove the KMS, buy a valid Windows 10 Pro license and update to Windwos 10 Version 1607.

Comment: As a student, there may be options to acquire Windows at a reduced price or free (via Dreamspark Premium or whatever it’s called now).

Comment: Well, i received this PC as a gift in december, what you say is possible for me, because in my country this kind of software is highly proliferated (specialy in prepared machines like mine), sometimes it is difficult distinguish from legal software to pirate, and sincerely i never put attention about that.

Answer (score 1):

It's part of Windows. It confirms you have a valid Windows license. Without it Office won't run, for example.

Recently it started interfering with my gaming, so I like to make sure it's not running while I'm playing. While nekotek's answer provides a way to turn it off completely (requires restart) I have a way to turn it off only during my playing sessions.

I've created a batch file that watches for this process and kills it every time it raises its head:

```
title Suppress SPP
:loop
taskkill /f /t /s localhost /im sppsvc.exe
timeout /t 3
goto loop
```

Copy this code to a text file with extension '.bat' (I called it "suppress spp.bat"). Place it anywhere you want on your computer and run it **as administrator** when you play, close it when you're done.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to fix this in Registry:

1. Go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\sppsvc`
2. Modify key `Start`, set it to `4`

Now the proccess is disabled. But, this will cause to inability to use **MS Office** and, after a while, Windows will be recognized as **not activated**

Next, you do **NOT** need to have a licenced copy of Windows, since people who have licenced copies experience this issue too.